# angular app animations not working with ng-repeat and bootstrap panel

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I am trying to work with the `ngAnimate` directive of angular but it is not working and also not showing any problem..

I had tried almost every thing but it didn't worked out.. 
the link to the my code is :

```js
// Code goes here

var ngTodo = angular.module('ngTodo', ['ngAnimate','ngStorage']);

ngTodo.controller('mainController',function($scope,$localStorage){
    
    $scope.todoArray = [];
    
    if($localStorage.todoArray == undefined){
            $localStorage.todoArray = $scope.todoArray;
        }
    else{
        $scope.todoArray = $localStorage.todoArray;
    }
    
    $scope.addTodo = function(newTodo){
        $scope.todoArray.splice(0,0, { title : newTodo.name, details : newTodo.details});
        $localStorage.todoArray = $scope.todoArray;
    }
    
    $scope.removeTodo = function(index){
        $scope.todoArray.splice(index,1);
        $localStorage.todoArray = $scope.todoArray;
    }
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.428;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image: url(../../images/bg-image.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
/* navbar top styles starts here */
input.search-todo-list{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top{
    background-color: #80bfff;
}
/* navbar top styles ends here */
/* content section starts here */
.content{
    margin-top: 64px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.empty-todo-list-message{
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.todo-item{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.panel-heading,
.panel-footer{
    padding: 5px 5px;
}
.panel-body{
    padding: 7px;
}
.panel-default>.panel-heading,
.panel-body,
.panel-footer{
    background-color: yellow;
}
/* content section starts here */
/* navbar bottom styles starts here */
.navbar-fixed-bottom input{
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom input,
button{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom{
    background-color: #80bfff;
}
/* navbar bottom styles ends here */

/* animation styles */
.move-animation.ng-move {
  transition: 1.75s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.move-animation.ng-move.ng-move-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ngTodo">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-animate.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.11/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="mainController">
        <!-- navbar top starts here -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img  width="40px" alt="Todo App Icon" class="img-circle img-responsive" src="assets/icon/icon.jpg">
                        </a>
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <h2 class="text-center">Today's Todo List</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="search..." ng-model="query" class="search-todo-list">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- navbar top ends here -->
        <!-- content section starts here -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 empty-todo-list-message" ng-if="todoArray.length == 0">
                        <div class="panel panel-default ">
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <h1><strong>Your Todo List is EMPTY</strong></h1>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- item starts here -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 todo-item" ng-repeat="todo in todoArray | filter : query" ng-animate=" 'animate' ">
                        <div class="panel panel-default ">
                          <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                            <h3><strong>{{ todo.title + " : "  }}</strong></h3>  
                          </div>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <strong>{{ todo.details}}</strong>
                          </div>
                          <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                            <button ng-click="removeTodo($index)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            delete</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- item ends here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- content section ends here -->
        <!-- navbar bottom starts here -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Add Todo Item" required ng-model="newTodo.name" >
                </div>
                <div class=" col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Add Todo Item Details" required  ng-model="newTodo.details">
                </div>
                <div class=" col-sm-2">
                    <button ng-click="addTodo(newTodo)" ><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add ToDo</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- navbar bottom ends here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you now help me out

Comment: minor improvement - ꜰʀᴏᴍ ʀᴇᴠɪᴇᴡ

Comment: what is your code doing? what are you expecting it to do?  right now, it's not clear what "it's not working" means.